# How to convert a double to an arbitrary-size byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-conversion

I am working on a project in ***C#*** where I have to extract data from a ***byte array*** using an opensource protocol called ***ASTERIX***. After I have modified data I want to encode them and put it in a ***byte array*** based on the protocol again. My problem is that at some point I need to convert a double to a byte array. Based on the protocol this byte array should be 3 bytes(3 OCTETS), whereas the byte array I get after conversion is 8 bytes. Is there any built-in function I can use to convert a double to a 3-byte byte array? 
Plus, the 3-byte is definitely enough for the double value I have. I have some code here if it will help:

```
double val = 32673.6953125;
byte[] brokenBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(doubleValue);;
```

[image]

Comment: A double has 8 bytes of data. How would you like to store that data in 3 bytes? This will be lossy and you need to tell us the format.

Comment: @usr You are absolutely right. had totally forgotten about the size of a double. Could you please tell what it is you want the format for?

Comment: How do you intend to put 8 bytes into 3?

Comment: @usr When I looked at some of the values converted to byte, it looked like I could get a vlaue of an index and add it to another index value as long as it is under 255. But then I realized: 1) it changes the value from the original 2) it is not possible to do the same with other double values.
But maybe you can help me with this: Is using `BitConverter` class the right way to convert values into byte array?

Comment: That's the right way but until you become clear on how you want to put 8 bytes into 3 this will go nowhere.

Comment: @usr For example, if you look at the image I uploaded; I thought I could take t the value in index 3 (128) and index 4 (108) add them together. Since the result is less than 255, I thought I could create a 3-byte array and add the result there. And do the same with other indexes. Like (index 3 + index 4). But this will go wrong in many ways. So I don't think it'll work

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that since a double needs at least 8 bytes, therefore; ***It is not possible to convert a double to an arbitrary-size byte array(in other words: squeeze it into a byte array smaller than 8 bytes) without losing precision and compromising the original value*** .

**Extra info:**
For anyone interested, after reading the documentation regarding the ASTERIX protocol I realized I needed to process the value through a given algorithm . This algorithm would then make it possible to store the value as a 3-byte(3-OCTET) data.
The specific data I needed to process is called ***Time Of Track Information***.
Here is the simple solution:

```
private double PrepareElapsedTimeSinceMidnightForEncodeing(double value, int numberOfDivisionBy2)
    {
        value *= 128;

        value /= Math.Pow(2, numberOfDivisionBy2);

        MainDataStorage.NumberOfDivisionBy2 = 0;

        return value;
    }
```

For more information regarding the ASTERIX protocol go to: [ASTERIX | Eurocontrol](http://www.eurocontrol.int/asterix)

Comment: Ideally this whole info should go as part of the question!

Comment: @Adarsha I'll do it now. sry

Comment: Where is the _array_ as in _"How to convert a double to an **arbitrary-size byte array?**"_

Comment: @Roy As usr mentioned int the comments a double needs 8-bytes, and you cannot force it into an array less than 8-bytes. My idea was (as stupid as it sounds) to get hold of a value in an index, and try to find another index. If their sum was less than 255, I would move the sum if those two values into a single index(e.g index3+index4 in the image). But that will never work.

Comment: I agree you cannot squish a double into 3 bytes, however your answer arguably shows no work along the lines of converting to a byte array - the essence of your question.

Comment: @Roy you are absolutely right. Forgetting a simple fact that double needs 8 bytes lead me to this question. I am not sure how I can answer this question in a correct way. Maybe I just need to mention I _It is not possible to do this without losing precision and compromising the original value?_ I am open to any suggestion you have :)

Comment: @arvind Yes I think that's a good idea. If you update your answer I can remove the nasty down-vote :)  Have a good day

Comment: @Roy Done and done. Hope you remove the down-vote now :) and thans for the help

Comment: Done. Not a problem. :)